# A is for... Latin examples

Tags: idiom

Are there any ancient—or modern, if not—examples of a learner's alphabet that mirrors the modern "A is for..."?

I'm not really looking for poetry that has an alphabet acrostic or any other playfulness, but **specifically for a standard construction of "is for" or "stands for" or "signifies" when used with alphabets**.

I know I could use *significare* (which Paulus uses to explain unfamiliar words) or *indicare*, but I don't know if they have Classical precedents specifically for this type of exercise.

Comment: In Portuguese(I guess in Spanish, too)we use the preposition "de" Any example "C de casa" I wondered if I could just translate this way. The reason I wondered: When we say "de" it suggests the letter came from that word, We take the letter "d" out of word "casa"

Answer (score 8):

The beginning of Orbis Pictus (1658) by Comenius has a list of sounds corresponding to the letters of the alphabet, meant for young students ("boys").

I have reproduced it from the 1748 edition of the Latin-German-Hungarian version (http://real-r.mtak.hu/624/, pdf pages 25-27), omitting the grammatical information on the nouns. The English translations are from the 1777 edition of Hoole's Latin-English version (http://books.google.nl/books?vid=OCLC27390661&pg=PA2).

The Magister (*Master*) tells the Puer (*Boy*): "Hic habes vivum et vocále Alphabétum" - "*Here thou hast a lively and vocal Alphabet*".

- A a: *Cornix* cornicátur (*The Crow crieth*), *á á*
- B b: *Ovis* balat (*The Lamb bleateth*), *bé é é* [the English version has 'Agnus']
- C c: *Cicáda* stridet (*The Grashopper chirpeth*), *cí cí*
- D d: *Úpupa* dicit (*The Whooppoo saith*), *du du*
- E e: *Infans* éjulat (*The Infant crieth*), *é é é*
- F f: *Ventus* flat (*The Wind bloweth*), *fi fi*
- G g: *Anser* gingrit (*The Goose gagleth*), *ga ga*
- H h: *Os* halat (*The Mouth breatheth out*), *háh háh*
- I i: *Mus* mintrit (*The Mouse chirpeth*), *í í í*
- K k: *Anas* tetrinnit (*The Duck quacketh*), *kha kha*
- L l: *Lupus* úlulat (*The Wolf howleth*), *lu ulu*
- M m: *Ursus* múrmurat (*The Bear grumbleth*), *mum mum*
- N n: *Felis* clamat (*The Cat crieth*), *nau nau*
- O o: *Auríga* clamat (*The Carter crieth*), *ó ó ó*
- P p: *Pullus* pipit (*The Chicken pippeth*), *pi pi*
- Q q: *Cucúlus* cucúlat (*The Cuckow singeth*), *kuk ku*
- R r: *Canis* ríngitur (*The Dog grinneth*), *err*
- S s: *Serpens* síbilat (*The Serpent hisseth*), *sí*
- T t: *Gráculus* clamat (*The Jay crieth*), *tac tac* [L&S: graculus = jackdaw]
- U u: *Bubo* úlulat (*The Owl hooteth*), *ú ú*
- W w: *Lepus* vagit (*The Hare squeaketh*), *vá*
- X x: *Rana* coaxat (*The Frog croaketh*), *coax*
- Y y: *Ásinus* rudit (*The Asse brayeth*), *y y y*
- Z z: *Tabánus* dicit (*The Breeze or Horse-fly saith*), *ds ds*

[I've added the acute accents in ásinus and úpupa. Coáxat and tetrínnit don't need them.]

Comment: This is great, but it isn't *quite* what I was looking for. But definitely a good find!